# Errors when updating MongoDB values from type Boolean to Number

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using mongodb, originally I have a schema defined like this

```
Service = new Schema( 
{
   ...: ...,
   ...: ...,
   additionalCards: {type:Boolean, default: false}
})
```

Then I have a lot of data records saved with field additionalCards as type boolean, value false.

Now I need to change the value type to Number, I made the change in schema to

```
additionalCards: {type:Number, default: 1}
```

Then I wrote a script to update database record which looks like this:

```
Service.update({additionalCards: false},{$set:{additionalCards:2}},function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

I thought this would be a easy update, however it gives me error like

```
{ message: 'Cast to number failed for value "false" at path "additionalCards"',
name: 'CastError', type: 'number',
value: false,
path: 'additionalCards' }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just do it in the shell or use the native node.js driver.

Comment: Or change the schema first. There is nothing wrong with the statement, it's just mongoose "type checking" on the schema that is getting in the way trying to "cast" a numeric as a Boolean. MongoDB itself does not care and will write what you ask it to. Also `0` and `1` would seem more logical replacements for `false` and `true`.

Comment: i tried native node.js command, which worked :)

Comment: Try `additionalCards: 0` instead of `additionalCards: false` in query :)